# where there is white edge line seen in 2.8

Tags: modeling

where there is white edge line seen in 2.8

[image]

**In 2.8** white Edge line

[image]

**In 2.79** No edge line seen

[image]

Why there is difference in both view. How can i solve it. Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Some UV mapping issue? Rendering artifact? Does it go away if you render it at a higher resolution? Are you rendering using cycles or eevee?

Comment: @Luciano in 2.79 & 2.8 cycles its not visible, only in 2.8 Eevee its visible

Comment: Have you set the *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Blend*?